# Version of Spring and Hibernate and jdk for Tomcat 10

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

do someone know which version of Spring, Hibernate and jdk may I use with Tomcat 10 and J2EE 9? Thanks for advice

Comment: What is J2EE 9? Java 2 Enterprise Edition 9?

Comment: There isn't any yet. Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3 will support JakartaEE.